# Django admin with FCGI + lighttpd

Tags: django, lighttpd, fastcgi

I'm running a django installation on lighttpd +FCGI.
Everything works fine except the admin.

It seems that the redirects after I post something (i.e. I modify sor create an instance of a model) go wrong.

The admin keeps redirecting me to www.xyz.com/django.fcgi/admin/... while django.fcgi should be used only by the lighttp rewrite rule to invoke FCGI.

Here's the redirection in the conf file

```
url.rewrite-once = (
                "^(/media.*)$" => "$1",
                "^/favicon\.ico$" => "/media/favicon.ico",
                    "^(/.*)$" => "/django.fcgi$1",
)
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The admin site is trying to work out the URL to use based on the SCRIPT_NAME variable passed by lighttpd, but that's the rewritten URL, not the original one. You can force Django to use the original path by adding the following to your settings.py file.

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = ""
```

See the [FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#force-script-name) documentation and the [Django FastCGI](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#forcing-the-url-prefix-to-a-particular-value) docs for more information.

Comment: Glad everything is working now. The best way to say thanks is with an up vote and to accept my answer - see the section "How do I ask questions here?" in http://stackoverflow.com/faq